# Error Deploying a WAR file in tomcat 7.0.50

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I had previously deployed a WAR file in tomcat installed on my local computer and it worked really fine. I am deploying the same WAR file on tomcat installed in my windows 2003 server and i get the following error. Below is my logfile.

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\ProgramFiles\ApacheSoftwareFoundatio\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\xxxxxxx.war
Sep 17, 2014 9:40:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig beforeStart
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/dstvNickGateway]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\dstvNickGateway.war (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:373)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 17, 2014 9:40:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : C:\Program  Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\dstvNickGateway.war (The process    cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5089)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 17, 2014 9:40:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component  [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xxxxxx]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5270)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 10 more

Sep 17, 2014 9:40:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software   Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\dstvNickGateway.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/dstvNickGateway]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: hm, the error says: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process! you are sure it's not used by another process (i.e. another tomcat instance which deploys the same war?)

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is already tomcat process running on your system. Try to kill java.exe from task manager and restart tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill all processes that could be locking the war file and restart your Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

The error say *The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process*. So it looks like you have another instance of Tomcat running. Kill all processes which may access the f

Answer (score 0):

tomcat is probably trying to unpack your war file while it's still being transferred. stop the server while you're uploading the file to avoid it doing this. when you're done with the ftp, then restart the tomcat server and hopefully it'll all be ok.